# BackendLessCollection<E> not casting to List<E>

Tags: android, backendless

The code below gets the data from server but can't cast to the List
This code show a error java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.tesla.developer.teslatvinverters.BackendlessClasses.InvertersData
Same Code is working fine for other backendless classes

```
  Backendless.Data.of(InvertersData.class).find(new    AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<InvertersData>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<InvertersData> inverterData) {
                // all Contact instances have been found

                // error is in the Toast when i try to get id of object , but it gives the size of data accurate

                List<InvertersData> allData = inverterData.getData();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" +allData.get(0).getObjectId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // iterate over the received objects
                Iterator<InvertersData> iterator = allData.iterator();

                while( iterator.hasNext())
                {

                     Log.e("Object  :", ""+iterator.next().getObjectId());
                }


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell Backendless how to cast your HashMap to class.

Put it somewhere during app init.

`Backendless.Persistence.mapTableToClass( "InvertersData", InvertersData.class );`